# Count up misspelled words in a sentence of variable size

Tags: python-3.x

as a part of a large project, I need a function that will check for any misspelt words in a sentence, however, this sentence can be one word or it can be 30 words or any size really.
It needs to be fast, if possible I would like to use text blob or pyspellcheck as python_language_tool has problems installing on my comp.

My code so far (non-working):

```
def spell2():
    from textblob import TextBlob
    count = 0
    sentence = "Tish soulhd al be corrrectt"
    split_sen = sentence.split(" ")
    for thing in split_sen:
        thing = Word(thing)
        thing.spellcheck()
        # if thing is not spelt correctly add to count, if it is go to 
        # next word
       
spell2()
```

this gives me this error:
thing = Word(thing)
NameError: name 'Word' is not defined

Any suggestions appreciated:)

Comment: Can you explain what it not working about it, and what problem you are having to get it to work?

Comment: When I run it, it spits this error    thing.spellcheck()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'spellcheck'

Comment: You are splitting `sentence` into a list of words (strings) - so far, so good.  Your loop then iterates over each word in that list one at a time - still all good.  But, when you get to `thing.spellcheck()` you have a problem.  `thing` is a string and Python strings do not have an attribute called `spellcheck`, so the interpreter gags on it.

Comment: Yea I  realized the structure should be like this gfg = Word("Prediction") and then go through gfg.spellcheck(), but in this case, I do not have the Word(). However, if I put it in, then there is another error, I'll edit the code provided and give the error.

Comment: Hi, nevermind, I found another route, I did it with spellchecker,  amount_miss = len(list(spell.unknown(sentence)))

Answer (score 0):

```
def spell3():
    from spellchecker import SpellChecker
    s = "Tish soulhd al be corrrectt, riiiigghtttt?"
    wordlist=s.split()
    spell = SpellChecker()
    amount_miss = len(list(spell.unknown(wordlist)))
    print("Possible amount of misspelled words in the text:",amount_miss)
   
spell3()
```